# Set a jasper report's datasource database name at run time

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

Jasper Studio will let you create a data source without specifying a db name.  Subsequently to you use a parameter to set the db name in your queries so that you can pull data from different databases based on the db name you pass in the URL string.

How can you add do this on jasper server?